# how can i get text with requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

huh, im getting this returned:
`[<div class="info"> <span class="text-title">Titoli alternativi: </span>OP<br/> <span class="text-title">Autore: </span>Eiichiro Oda<br/> <span class="text-title">Data di Uscita Jap: </span>20 Ottobre 1999<br/> <span class="text-title">Genere: </span>Azione, Avventura, Commedia, Drammatico, Fantasy, Superpoteri, Shounen<br/> <span class="text-title">Durata: </span>24 min<br/> <span class="text-title">Episodi: </span>??? – <i>(In Corso)</i><br/> <span class="text-title">Trama: </span>Monkey D. Rufy è`

but im only able to get each text-title, it's returned as a string so i can't access each of them and use regex, is there any elegant method to do it?

```
r = requests.get("https://www.animeuniverse.it/one-piece-ita-streaming-download/")
    status = (r.ok); titles = []; descs= []#returns true if status code is <400> (no errors)
    if status == True:
        try:
            with open("index.html","x")as f:
                f.write(r.text)
        except:
            os.remove("index.html")
            with open("index.html","x")as f:
                f.write(r.text)
        with open("index.html", "r") as f:
            r = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")


            info_data = r.find_all(class_="info")
            #info_data = list(info_data)
            #print (info_data)
            #print (len(info_data))
            #print (type(info_data))
            #print (info_data[0])
```

Comment: post your code, please. what text do you want?

Comment: Provide python code

Comment: Can edit your question? I

Comment: Can you define your question with what you actually want to get? If there is no secrets, can you also provide a site url?

Comment: huh yeah, edited it

Comment: i want to get, for example: "OP" and "20 Ottobre 1999"

Comment: @kekkoilmedikit, you won't be able to scrape this url, because this site is protected with cloudflare. You are better now to search for Cloudflare bypass library, and try to use them. Note that they do not always work, so you can end up with situation, where you won't be able to scrape anything

Comment: i'm already getting the first title ("Titoli alternativi" ecc)

Comment: guess it's not that protected lmao

Answer (score 0):

huh, fixed it anyway, didn't need any cloudflare bypass or else, here's the fix:

```
            info_data = r.find_all(class_="info-anime")
            info_data = str(info_data)
            info_data = info_data.splitlines()
            info_data.pop(0)
            for data in info_data:
                # print (data)
                # print ("============")
                try:
                    data = re.search('</span>(.+?)<', data).group(1)
                    if len(data) > 100:
                        plot.append(data)
                    #print (data)
                    else:
                        descs.append(data)
                except AttributeError:
                    data = data[:-7]
                    plot.append(data)
```